# High dimensional wave equation

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, field-theory, classical-field-theory

In 3 dimensions, the wave equation
$$\Box\psi=\delta(t)\delta(\vec{x})$$
has the retarded and advanced solutions
$$\psi=A_R \frac{\delta(t-x)}{4\pi x} + A_A \frac{\delta(t+x)}{4\pi x}.$$
How does this generalize to higher dimensions?

Comment: Are you asking what the differential *equation* is in higher dimensions? Or what the *solutions* are?

Comment: Surely you can adapt [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function#Table_of_Green's_functions).

Comment: ... or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1095435/dalembert-operator-green-function-in-arbitrary-dimension).

Comment: ...or [THIS one](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.66.025016). Can you fold it into your question?

Comment: Umm, I'm not sure how to do "fold" it into my question. But let me check the link, if it's good then I guess the problem is resolved.

Comment: I am looking for the solution.

Comment: The two papers look good. I will mark this question as closed if you post the links as an answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105007/discussion-between-k-sadri-and-cosmas-zachos).

Comment: Please explain what are $A_R$ and $A_A$ in your question. You can perhaps give their expressions to make the question self-contained. @K.Sadri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, by the OP's invitation, the two papers addressing his question are

- [Greens Functions for the Wave Equation,
  A H Barnett 2006](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.170.6934&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

and

- [D V Gal'tsov 2002](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.66.025016).

The idea is to  express the *N*-dimensional Laplacian  in polar coordinates, $\frac{1}{r^{N-1}} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left(r^{N-1} \frac{\partial }{\partial r} \right)$.